# Relations in prime numbers

Tags: prime-numbers, real-numbers

In the spirit of my previous question, an approximate sum of prime numbers smaller or equal than a given number 'n'  can be found by the following formula
$$\frac{n^{2}}{\ln(n^{2})-1}$$

For example if $n=10^{8}$, the value obtained is $2.7900725823\cdot10^{14}$. The real value is $279209890387283$, the question is, whether this connection (and reason) between the number of prime numbers and the sum of prime numbers has already been noticed in the literature?

Comment: This is coming from the general fact that $$
\sum\limits_{p \le n}^{} {p^\alpha  }  \sim \pi (n^{\alpha  + 1} ) \sim \operatorname{Li}(n^{\alpha  + 1} ) \sim \frac{{n^{\alpha  + 1} }}{{\log (n^{\alpha  + 1} ) - 1}}
$$ for any $\alpha \geq 0$. See, e.g., https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s11139-016-9847-4

Comment: Don't refer to "my previous question", this is useless and uniformative.

Comment: If you are going to require that people answer in a specific way, you should tell them what that way is so they don't waste their time.

Comment: It is an easy corollary of the **prime number theorem** which is the main achievement of the theory of the Riemann zeta function.

Comment: comment on the first comment ... I'm not sure .. my approach is different